# How to Solve Number System Problem

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, decimal-expansion, number-systems

**The Problem**

Below is a problem dealing with number systems:

[image: The Problem. It gives the cubes of numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive, as well as a randomized list of those cubes translated into Ngkolmpu, a language spoken by around 100 people in New Guinea. The problem is to match the translations to the Arabic numeral cubes.]

**My Attempt**

Since *traowo*,*ptae*,*tarumpao* appear repeatedly and in consistent positions, I assumed they were conjunctions similar to "and" in "two-hundred and thirty".

Thus 1) would be 5 digits, 2) would be 2 digits, 3) would be 1 digit, 4) would be 3 digits, 5) would be 5 digits, 6) would be 2 digits, 7) would be 1 digit, 8) would be 5 digits, 9) would be 3 digits, and 10) would be 5 digits.

Since there are 2 one-digit numbers(*naempr* and *tarumpao*), and the smallest ones in the list of cubes are 1 and 8, they must match. And since they are one-digit and the biggest one is 8, b > 8.

There are two two-digit numbers(*eser traowo yuow* and *naempr traowo yempoka*), and these must thus correspond to the next smallest cubes, 27 and 64. Take *naempr traowo yempoka*. Assume that *naempr* is 8. Then since b > 8, 8b > 64, and *naempr traowo yempoka* > 8b, but *naempr traowo yempoka* has to be either 27 or 64 so it is not possible. Thus *naempr* is 1 and *tarumpao* is 8.

Consider *naempr traowo yempoka*. This equals 1*b + c, for some number c < b. The maximum value of c is b - 1, so the maximum value of this number is b + b - 1 = 2b - 1. For this number to be 27 or 64, 2b - 1 cannot be less than 27, so 2b - 1  ≥ 27 → b ≥ 14.

Now consider *naempr ptae eser traowo eser*. This would be $b^{2} + cb + c$, and so the maximum value of this is $b^{2} + (b - 1)b + (b - 1)$ → $2b^{2} - 1$. Because there are two three-digit numbers, this must be equal to 125 or 216, so it has to be less than 343. But solving the equation $2b^{2} - 1 \space < \space 343$ gives b < 14, which is a contradiction of what we found earlier.

Could someone please explain this to me? I don't understand where I went wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint:  Ngkolmpu is (somewhat) well known for being one of the very few languages to use a senary digit system (a.k.a "base six").

Comment: @lulu so is it like where base-10 English has "eleven" for 11 > 10?

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning.  As we are working in base $6$, you'll need a word for $6^3$.  That happens to be tarumpao.  For example.

Comment: I don't know how to attack this without knowing the base $6$ fact.  Once you know that, you know that you'll need words for $6^2,6^3$.  Happily $6^4$ is out of the range.  And of course you need the names of the numbers $1, \cdots, 6$.  Easy to look all of that up, or I expect there's enough information to deduce it.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much!

Comment: You can suspect a lower base since there are only so many words used here. Apart from the words like traowo/ptae/tarumpao which seem to indicate digit location (similar to thousand/hundred/ten) there aren't that many words left that can denote the digits. Also the length of each number name suggests that there are several 4-digit numbers among them.